# change <div> style with typescript base on condition

Tags: html, css, typescript, dom

i try to change  style with typescript base on condition.
html :

```
<div class="table-main" id="table-main" (load)="zoom()">
```

typescript:

```
 zoom() {
    if (x === `y`) {
          style 1
    } else {
      style 2
    }
```

if condition true => change zoom property=> zoom: "110%" else zoom: "90%".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick demo for you to get started.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-zoom]').forEach(element => {
  const condition = element.dataset.zoom
  
  if(condition === 'true') {
    element.style.zoom = '400%'
  }
})
```

```html
<div data-zoom="true">
  test01
</div>

<div data-zoom="false">
  test02
</div>
```